# Laravel: update the oldest token of user

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am currently working on the creation of an API using Lumen. I have, for the example, 2 tables `users` and `users_token` with the corresponding models `User` and `UsersToken`:

*App\User:*

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'firstname',
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
        'password',
        'email_verified_at'
    ];


    public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UsersToken', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

*App\UsersToken:*

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UsersToken extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users_token';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'token',
    ];
}
```

The table `users_token` has 2 importants fields: `user_id` (foreign key linked with `id` field from `users` table) and `token` (a simple string).

In my model `User`, I have the method `tokens` that return all the tokens from the user using the `hasMany()` function:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UsersToken');
    }
}
```

The table `users_token` also contains the defaults fields `created_at` and `updated_at`. So to get the oldest modified token of an user, I decide to use the `oldest()` and `first()` functions of Laravel:

```php
$latestUserToken = $user->tokens->oldest('updated_at')->first();
```

So then I just have to update the value `token` of it and finally `save()` it:

```php
$latestUserToken = $user->tokens->oldest('updated_at')->first();
$latestUserToken->token = 'test';
$latestUserToken->save();
```

But sadly I get this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `users_token` set `token` = test, `users_token`.`updated_at` = 2020-04-06 17:34:59 where `id` is null)

If I make a `print_r` of `$user->tokens->oldest('updated_at')->first()` I get this:

```
[withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 11
            [token] => IsSdh03fKS3NCpfVmfm8XZyK1uYf2hSb3nRkojo86XRN7zdZnRqEOZe2HvXT
            [created_at] => 2020-04-05 17:18:22
            [updated_at] => 2020-04-01 17:18:22
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 11
            [token] => IsSdh03fKS3NCpfVmfm8XZyK1uYf2hSb3nRkojo86XRN7zdZnRqEOZe2HvXT
            [created_at] => 2020-04-05 17:18:22
            [updated_at] => 2020-04-01 17:18:22
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [classCastCache:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

)
```

Have someone an idea where my error is?

Comment: Can you also give the UserToken model please?

Comment: @omarjayed Yeah sure here you go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many different ways to generate the error in my workspace. The only time I could generate it is not having the `id` column in `users_token` table. And it looks like there's no `id` column in `users_token` table.

If not defined explicitly, Eloquent will look for the field `id` as the primary key for any table. You can define the primary key field name on model using `protected $primaryKey = 'token';`. I'm assuming you want the field `token` as the primary key.

But I would recommend not to use `token` as the primary. Use the plain old auto-increment long integer as the primary key and use `token` as a unique key. That will prevent any unwanted duplicate entry.

The rest of the code looks okay.

Comment: Yeah I don't have an `id` column in `users_token` table because initially I wanted a composite primary key from `token` and `user_id`. I think that I will follow your advice and just add the default `id` column. Thanks for your Help ;)

Comment: Glad to help... :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you review printing

```
$latestUserToken = $user->tokens->oldest('updated_at')->first();
```

I think that is a hybrid between user and user_token so isn't a clear instance to update.

Also you can review users_token table structure (primary key).

Comment: Interesting question actually I don't have defined the primary key of `UsersToken` because it's the composite of the field `user_id` and `token`

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49931126/13112515 or simply consider add a primary key.

Comment: Yes using a simple primary key like the field `token` work well. If you write this answer with an example I will validate your answer

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent doesn't support **composite** primary keys.

if you want to reach that you should override two methods and override `$primary_key` attribute.

in *App\UsersToken:*

```php
class UsersToken extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users_token';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'token',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = [
        'user_id',
        'token',
    ];

    /**
     * Set the keys for a save update query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query)
    {
        $keys = $this->getKeyName();
        if (! is_array($keys)) {
            return parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
        }

        foreach ($keys as $keyName) {
            $query->where($keyName, '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName));
        }

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * Get the primary key value for a save query.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $keyName
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName = null)
    {
        if (null === $keyName) {
            $keyName = $this->getKeyName();
        }

        return $this->original[$keyName] ?? $this->getAttribute($keyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I think I already read something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5. But I think I will stay with the use of a single primary key